# no match for operator!=

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I am trying to create linked list class and define the iterators, I have all of them except the last one. I dont get how to fix, i get this error when i compile my code:

> no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘recList.SortedList::begin with T = Record != recList.SortedList::end with T = Record’
>   a1q1main.cpp:114:37: note: candidates are:
>   sortedlist.h:112:11: note: SortedList::iterator SortedList::iterator::operator!=(bool) [with T = Record, SortedList::iterator = SortedList::iterator]
>   sortedlist.h:112:11: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘SortedList::iterator’ to ‘bool’

It keeps on displaying this error no matter what i do
I have declared operator == and everything is fine but the != complains
Here is the code :

```
 class SortedList {
 struct Node {
    T data_;
    Node* next_;
    Node* prev_;
    Node(const T& data = T{}, Node* next = nullptr, Node* prev = nullptr) {
        data_ = data;
        next_ = next;
        prev_ = prev;
    }
};
Node* head_;
Node* tail_;
    public:
class const_iterator {
protected:
    Node* curr_;
public:
    const_iterator(Node* p) {
        curr_ = p;
    }
 .........
    const_iterator operator--(int) {
        const_iterator tmp = *this;
        curr_ = curr_->prev_;
        return tmp;
    }
    const T& operator*() const {
        return curr_->data_;
    }


     const_iterator operator==(bool){
            return false;
     }

    const_iterator operator!=(bool){
            return true;
    }

return;`
```

I need to fulfill the criteria below:
 operator !=
returns true if two iterators point at different nodes, false otherwise
O(1)

I did not complete the logic of the operator, i just need to declare it properly so i dont get the error

Comment: `operator!=` (in most cases) takes another iterator and returns a bool, check your signature

Comment: signature should be like [`bool operator!=(L, R);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison). As a standalone friend function. Or probably `bool operator!=(OTHER)` as member. You have defined them as taking a bool argument and returning an iterator.

Comment: first of all if i add two parameters to the function it complains and says i need to pass one parameter only, second of all bool operator!=() does not change the situation and the same error pops up

Answer (score 1):

The signature of your operator overloads are incorrect. You have them accepting a bool and returning an iterator. It should be the other way around.

Consider the operation you are performing

```
if(it1 == it2){
    // do stuff
}
```

You even return a bool in your functions despite the signature requiring a iterator as return value.

Instead implement the operator overloads in the required signature

```
bool operator==(sorted_list_iterator it){
    return (curr_->data_ == it.curr_->data_);
}

bool operator!=(sorted_list_iterator it){
    return !(*this == it);
}
```

Note you can use your `operator==` overload in your `operator!=` to avoid repeating the equality logic in two functions. You may also be required to allow for a null `curr_` in those functions.

Comment: cool well if this answer is useful feel free to upvote and mark as accepted, so that anyone with the same issue in the future can be confident to use this answer.